# Finding matching words in a vector (array) of strings

Tags: r

I have 2 columns in the dataset such as:

```
Col1                Col2
Kettle              Russel Hobs Kettle
Kettle              Russel H Kettle
Kettle              Toyota Kettle
Rice Cooker         Hobs Cooker
Russel Rice Cooker  Russel Cooker
```

I want to find the `%` of times that the words 'Russel' OR 'Hobs' appear in the 2nd column GIVEN that they don't appear in the 1st one.

**Step 1.** Find the `%` of times 'Russel' OR 'Hobs' appears in a Vector.

If want to create a for loop from 1 to the size of dataset.

Each row will check if `'Russel' OR 'Hobs' in the dataset$Col2[I]`

I wrote the following code:

```
n=0
for (i in 1:7406){
  if ( 'Russel' %in% dataset$Col2[i] | 'Hobs' %in% dataset$Col2[i])
    {n <- n+1}
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working as n stays at 0. I also have a problem with Case Sensitivity, but I guess the best way to treat is it to convert the whole dataset to lower?
Hence, `n` would give us the number of rows with the brand and I simply need to find `n/I=4/5` in this example.

**Step 2.**

First check if 'Russel' or 'Hobs' appear in the first column. If they do, simply increment the count. Hence we use the NOT parameter ! for our loop.

```
if (! 'Russel' %in% dataset$Col1[I]) { }
```

But now I will also add another counter, to track the number of words which don't contain the words in the first Col.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible and add your expected output

Comment: @Sotos I guess the main question is why does 'russel' %in% 'russel kettle' evaluate to FALSE?

Comment: Well, because it is not `%`in`%` there. Try `'russel' %in% c('russel', 'kettle')` to see the difference. For your case you are looking for `grepl`, i.e. `grepl('russel', 'russel kettle' )`

Comment: Great, this seems to work now. I also added the | operator in there.